# Questions about the source of defmulti

Tags: clojure

1. I couldn't help notice that the author prefers calling `(first options)` multiple times over *caching* the result:

   ```
   [docstring   (if (string? (first options))
                  (first options)
                  nil)
    options     (if (string? (first options))
                  (next options)
                  options)
    m           (if (map? (first options))
                  (first options)
                  {})
    options     (if (map? (first options))
                  (next options)
                  options)
    ...]
   ```

I assume this is ok (in terms of performance) because it is defining a macro, which will be executed during compilation?

2. I'm still not sure if I understand the evaluation process of calling a macro. Using `(defmulti ...)` as an example, correct me if I'm wrong: during compilation, the macro is *expanded*, of which the result is a call to the special `let` form, which is in turn translated into bytecode. Then what?
3. Pretending we are defining a fn instead of a macro, is it worth it to introduce an extra symbol to *cache* the result of `(first options)`:

   ```
   [f           (first options)
    docstring   (if (string? f)
                  f
                  nil)
    options     (if (string? f)
                  (next options)
                  options)
    f           (first options)
    m           (if (map? f)
                  f
                  {})
    options     (if (map? f)
                  (next options)
                  options)
    ...]
   ```
4. What exactly does it mean that a var `hasRoot`? And what is an `Unbound`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, calling `first` is fast. The varargs are represented as a sequence, specifically a `clojure.lang.ArraySeq` (at least up until a certain number of arguments).

   ```
   user=> ((fn [& args] (type args)) 1 2 3)
   clojure.lang.ArraySeq
   ```

   The implementation of `first()` on `ArraySeq` is an array lookup

   ```
   public Object first(){
       if(array != null)
           return array[i];
       return null;
   }
   ```

   https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ArraySeq.java#L69
2. Then the bytecode is then loaded into the JVM and executed.
3. I doubt that will make a difference.
4. A var can have thread-locale bindings, meaning it's possible for each thread to see a different value. The root binding is the value the var is initialized with. A thread-locale binding does not squash the root binding, it just shadows it. An `Unbound` is a implementation optimization for vars that are created without a root binding.

   Take a look at [`clojure.core/binding`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding) for how to set thread-locale values.